# ¿Cómo borro un directorio con nombre demasiado largo en windows?

Tags: cmd, windows10

Debido a un error en un plugin de maven se crearon carpetas con el mismo nombre una dentro de otra en cierta carpeta y no puedo eliminarlas.

Al tratar de eliminarlas obtengo el siguiente error

[image: Source Path Too Long]

Que dice que la ruta de la carpeta que está más abajo es mayor de los creo 256 caracteres que soporta Windows.

Quisiera saber si alguien conoce algún comando de CMD que pueda usar para eliminar estas carpetas.

Intentos:

```
rd /s /q directory
```

> The system cannot find the path specified.

```
rd -r directory
```

> The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> The directory is not empty.

Nota: Normalmente para salir de problemas bootearía otro sistema operativo desde una memoria para borrar la carpeta, pero esa no es una opción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude resolverlo con los siguientes pasos:

- Ir al directorio ofensor
- crer un directorio llamado empty en la raíz
- llamar la utilidad [robocopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) para copiar todas las carpetas internas al directorio "empty"

  `cd c:/..../directory`

  `mkdir \empty`

  `robocopy /mir \empty directory`

Tras tener estos pasos, puedes borrar sin problemas la carpeta "empty" que estará en tu raíz ( no importa si no ves contenido ), en mi caso `C:/empty` y las carpetas desaparecerán.